# How to select option from dynamic dropdown

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I got a problem with choosing an option from a dynamic dropdown.
I've already tried several options: 
- by choosing from the select list (in the 'target' i tried (label, index, value))
- by choosing from the div id="id_language_chzn (in the 'target' i tried (label, index, value))

Nothing supposed to work !

Code is here: http://pastebin.com/v3Q7NDGs

Regards if could help me on this,
Szymon

Comment: I saw your code but I didnt understand, which language are you using? I had the same problem in python... Maybe I can help you because the functions are similar

Comment: @Lara I'm using html/css for the selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Use a little delay after the page load, very likely the JS did not initialize completely.
http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#pause
 Also for this Chosen problem, click on the dynamically created element itself, do not use the html form element.

Comment: The delay doesn't seem to work. There is no JS loading while choosing an option.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
By ddLocator = By.xpath(".//select[1]");
By items = By.xpath(".//option");
ByChained comboBox1 = new ByChained( ".//select[1]", ".//option" ); 
List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.getElements( comboBox1 );
for ( WebElement we : allOptions ) {
  // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it occurred that selenium IDE had some problems with taking out the selected option. I have used webdriver and it helped.

Here is the code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.class > span")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("id_name[1]")).click();
```